# PTV Developer: Track zombies

Tags: ptv-developer

We do run a lot of interfaces 24/7 and have seen the strangest things in TCP/IP communication. In connection with PTV Developer I have the following questions:

What happens when we do **not delete map matching tracks** with deleteMatchedTrack?

The usual call sequence is like that:

- 1st: createMatchedTrack
- 2nd: getMatchedTrack polling for the ID from the response of the first call till the status is SUCCEEDED or FAILED and not longer RUNNING
- 3rd: deleteMatchedTrack for the ID from the response of the first call

Given there is an issue, that interrupts that sequence, then there will be track zombies that no one will cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration provides 7d as lifetime by default and 1h after the first GET request for an ID.
So there will be no zombie tracks on the system.
We will add this information in the documentation for PTV Developer asap.

Comment: Thanks. That is good to know and I appreciate the addition to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to ask the same question. From my POV if PTV is not answering this question, just ignore the zombies till they give you a call that you have created too much zombies.

I am not aware of any information in the documentation at https://developer.myptv.com/Documentation.htm that tells us something about the life time of tracks or anything else that has a creation and deletion method in the API. Maybe there is an automatic cleanup after a reasonable amount of time. I would not expect that I can access something that I created months ago, but this is my opinion and not deep PTV Developer knowledge. (maybe there are exceptions to the expectation if it is something like a profile)

If there is no automatic cleanup and PTV cares about too much zombies, then my suggestion for the PTV Developer devs / PM is an additional parameter were I can specify the lifetime. For my current Map Matching implementation this parameter would be not more than five minutes, because I do abort the getMatchedTrack polling loop after some time and call deleteMatchedTrack.